# Transparency control (Non transparent control in transparent container)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5, mxml

In one of my component, I want some of the control not transparent at all. Is there a way to switch-off transparency in Flex? I mean, if a parent container has more than one controls in it, then one to be not transparent at all.

If we set a higher value of alpha, there is some degree of transparency always present. This will complicate situation if a component inside "the non transparent" container is needing some degree of transparency.

Adding sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
     alpha=".4" >
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" gap="0"/>
</s:layout>
<!-- following container should not be transparent -->
<s:BorderContainer width="90%" height="20%" backgroundColor="white">

</s:BorderContainer>
<s:Group width="90%" height="80%">
    <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%" alpha="1">

    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:Group>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: If all else fails... just create your own user interface (add AS3 shapes or even load PNG files?) and then you can control each item by code to respond to user dragging, clicking etc and also since your code knows the individual items you added to the stage (display list) you can use it to affect individual transparency etc.

Comment: This is the option I had to use finally, though I do not like it at all. Need ability to set opaque child that can have transparent childens.

Comment: Then just declare `MovieClip` or `Sprite` variables as containers for content by using `addChild`. So now you can try.. `mc_Opaque.addChild( mc_Trans );` and to change alpha of **mc_Trans** (inside mc_Opaque) it becomes  like `mc_Opaque.mc_Trans.alpha = 0.4;`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you are asking is not possible.  Instead, you could set the transparency of the parent and only set the transparency of the required children as needed.